# Finding users who load more than 10% of the network

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hashmap, hashtable

I need to improve a working solution for this problem :

A system gets messages from users in the network.
Every time a user posts a message, we increase the total counter (totCounter) and the user's messages counter (userMessagesCounter) for this user. For that, we have a hash map with users(keys) and userMessagesCounter(values).
Therefore, to get the users who sent more than 10% messages in the network, All we do is iterating over the hash table, checking for each user if (userMessagesCounter / totCounter) > 0.1 , and if so, we add the user key to an ArrayList. At the end we return this list.
This takes O(n) cause we iterate over all the users.

I need to improve this system making it run the fastest I can.
What I thought about was this fact : there couldn't be more than 10 users with more than 10% load (cause then we have more than 100%).
Therefore, I can make an array of size 10 and updating it when a message arrives. The problem is when a new message arrives, this array information might not be valid anymore and I need to recheck all the array elements for each message that arrives.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem in O(10) (which is like O(1) actually) using the idea I came up with ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for frequent mining algorithm, that looks for an item that repeats `theta` (in your case `theta=0.1`) of the times in the collection.

An approach to handle it using `1/theta` space in linear time was proposed by Karp-Papadimitriou-Shanker: [A Simple Algorithm for Finding Frequent
Elements in Streams and Bags](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Esamir/498/karp.pdf)

```
1. PF = ∅
2. foreach element e∈S {
3. if PF.hasKey(e) { // increase counter
4. PF.value(e)++ // of existing elements
5. }
6. Else {
7. PF.insert(e,1) // insert new element
8. If |PF|== 1/θ { // but if PF is full
9. Foreach key ∈ PF {
10. PF.value(k)-- // decrease all counters
11. if PF.value(k) == 0 { // and remove
12. PF.remove(k) // elements at 0
13. } } } } }
14. Output PF
```

Pseudo code taken from [lecture notes in Tehcnion's big data course](http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236620/Spring2013/ho/WCFiles/Lec10-steaming.pdf)

In here, your "stream" is the messages sent, and when you are looking for the users with frequent messages - check the current candidates in `PF`, which is `O(1)` for the constant `theta=0.1`.

This algorithm yields `1/theta` (10 in your case) candidates for being "frequent", but it has False Positives - it means it might point something as "possibly frequent", while it isn't - but that shouldn't be hard for you, as you can simply verify it,

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a nearly O(1) solution here:

Maintain a dictionary that has the list of users and their message count.

You have a list of the 10% users.  These are links to the dictionary records, not local copies.

When you get a message you look up that user and increment their message count.  This is O(1) as it's a dictionary. If the count is less than 10%, exit.

If this user is already in the 10% list, exit.  This is O(4) if the list is sorted by user, O(10) otherwise.

Add this user to the 10% list.

Purge the list of any users that are no longer 10% users.  O(10) at the worst.

Upon a request for the list:

Purge the list of any users that are no longer 10% users.  Again, O(10) at the worst--this is the same routine as above.

return a copy of the list.